# What is the indent variable of enumerate?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

When using an option for enumerate the indent before the items disappears. I would like to set the indent to the same indent that is naturally used for itemize, enumerate etc., but I don't know how to get the value for this natural indent. I tried `\begin{enumerate}[\hspace{\leftmargin}a)]` but that produces an indent far too wide.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate} 

\begin{document}
  \noindent Text
  \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It'd be helpful if you complete your code snippet to a minimal working example. This is a short document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and contains as few lines of code/text as are necessary to reproduce the issue. This is in particular important because you appear to be using either the [`enumerate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) package or the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package (with the `shortlabels` option).

Comment: There are `\leftmargini`, `\leftmarginii`, `\leftmarginiii` and `\leftmarginiv` for the different enumeration levels. A better way to control those values is  provided by package `enumitem`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer all produce an indent that is far wider than the "normal" indent

Comment: @Katy: Well, I actually meant to modify them, but rather use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` if you insist on the `[a)]` syntax and then take a look on `labelindent` etc. values

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the question is what value I use for modification. I want it to be aligned with other itemize and enumerate lists. So I need to know what indent they are using

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\usepackage{enumerate}`, you can use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`. This powerful package has a lot of different options to configure the appearance of lists, check out the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) if you want to learn more about it.

The `shortlabels` option adds the `[a)]` functionality, and there it automatically gets the indentation right. So this produces the desired output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm working within a pretty big project. If I change the use of the package enumerate to enumitem, won't that potentially mess up stuff somewhere else?

Comment: @Katy: From the documentation: "[shortlabels] is intended mainly as a sort of compatibility mode with the `enumerate` package". I cannot guarantee that it won't break anything in your project, you can only find out by trying, I guess.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: While the question title is about the "indent variable", the question body is actually about "How do I get this label type with the natural indentation". This is taken care of by `enumitem` without the use of any indent variable.